# Is it possible to edit site template before it can be used again to make more sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to edit site template before it can be used again to make more sites ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. A site template is a package that contains a set of differences from a base site definition.

Below are the Pros & Cons of Site Template

**Site Template Pros**:-

Site templates enable administrators to create predefined sites to simplify site provisioning from a user perspective. Sites that are created with them are consistent, which improves usability and maintenance. The pages are stored in just one location—the content database.

**Site Template Cons**:-

Because the pages are stored in the content database, performance degradation could occur. **Once you create and save a template, you can't update it, which might lead to future product compatibility issues**.

Comment: Is above information is useful to you? If yes than please mark the answer so others can get benefit of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, but what is usually done:

1) You create a site to use as the basis for a template

2) You save the site as a template

3) You create multiple sites based on the template

4) You modify the site basis (the one created in step 1)

5) You create the template again and delete the old one.

6) You create new sites. Based on the template of step 5.

With this scheme can be improving the site template in different versions.

If you need more information, let me know. I'm working on a project more than a year of development. The whole project is based on creating template-based sites.